# How do I run Google's aefix tool when upgrading a Google App Engine app to the flexible environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to upgrade a Google App Engine app from the standard environment to the flexible environment. I am having an issue similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874226/google-app-engine-import-issue-golang-in-app-engine-flexible-environment-fo), except I am only seeing the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [go].  Please correct the errors and try again.`

I cannot find a log which details the missed requirements.

Google describes how to update an older (standard) app to the flexible environment [here](https://github.com/golang/appengine#updating-a-go-app-engine-app). They suggest running the `aefix` tool, but there are no instructions on how to run the tool. I ran `go get google.golang.org/appengine/cmd/aefix` to install it. I also looked through [the source code](https://github.com/golang/appengine/tree/master/cmd/aefix) and saw the following usage requirement: `usage: aefix [-diff] [-r fixname,...] [-force fixname,...] [path ...]`. However, the `aefix` command is not found. (I also tried running the compiled binary at `$GOPATH/bin/aefix`, but it just hangs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, that documentation was out of date. I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/golang/appengine/pull/61) to fix it.

Those APIs (mostly) do not work from App Engine flexible. They're only useful from Standard.

See the [documentation on cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading) on migrating an app from the standard environment to flexible.